# Performance impact of Resque worker re-establishing connecting in after_fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, redis, rails-activerecord, resque

I am trying to understand the performance impact of doing this:

```
Resque.before_fork do
    Rails.logger.info "in resque.rake before fork"
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

Resque.after_fork do
    Rails.logger.info "in resque.rake after fork"
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Doesn't doing this significantly affect performance as we are no longer holding a persistent connection to the DB and doing this again and again in every job. In my case the work the job does is very small. All it does is insert a record as shown below:

```
Foo.create(:name => "Hello World")
```

Since the work is so small, I am wondering if doing it in a job is actually hurting performance. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that those statements are there in order to prevent failing on connecting to a database in the event that a Resque job fails and needs to be retried.  See [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1339) ... It sounds like this is mostly a problem with postgres, but it may be an issue with other databases as well.

My gut tells me that the performance impact is going to be minimal, but you could always try removing those lines and testing it on a staging environment for a bit of time before moving it to production, but I'd personally leave it.